# Why can't access rails application on production environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When run the development mode, it works well:

```
$ rails s
```

But when the production mode:

```
$ RAILS_ENV=production rails s
```

And try to access it:

```
$ curl http://0.0.0.0:3000
```

Then message is:

```
Access denied.
```

There isn't any error log. Can't find what's the reason.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you completed these steps before you ran `rails s -e production`.

1. `bundle exec rake db:create RAILS_ENV=production`
2. `bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production`
3. `bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`

then you can run: `bundle exec rails s -e production`

Comment: Thank you. I'm sure I did that. And I can't see any log generated to log/production.log

Comment: try to run `rails s -e production` instead of `rails s RAILS_ENV=production`